# Derived functor of $H^0$

Tags: category-theory, homology-cohomology, abelian-categories, sheaf-cohomology, derived-functors

Let $R$ be a commutative unitary ring and $\mathrm{Mod}_R$ be the category of $R$-modules and $C := \mathrm{Ch}_{\geq 0}(\mathrm{Mod}_R)$ be the category of chains of $R$-modules which are zero in negative degree. Then we have a functor $H^n: C \to \mathrm{Mod}_R, M^{\bullet} \mapsto H^0(M^{\bullet})$. Since $H^n$ vanishes on exact sequences, $H^n$ induces a functors in the derived category: $H^n_1: D(\mathrm{Mod}_R) \to \mathrm{Mod}_R$.

On the other hand, I have the functor $H^0: C \to \mathrm{Mod}_R$ which induces a functor $D(H^0): D(\mathrm{Mod}_R) \to D(\mathrm{Mod}_R)$. I want to show that $H^n_1 = H^n_1 \circ D(H^0)$. Does anybody know how to prove this?

Comment: Isn't $D(H^0)$ a functor from $D(C)$ ? You can compose with the inclusion $\iota:\operatorname{Mod}_R\to C, M\mapsto M[0]$, but I doubt this is what you want since $H^0\circ\iota$ is the identity.

Comment: Doesnt $H^0$ first factor trough the homotopy category $K(\mathrm{Mod}_R)$ and then $D(\mathrm{Mod}_R)$? How does the composition with the inclusion help?